# Inequality Problem involving exponential expression

Tags: inequality

How do I prove the following inequality :

$$\frac{2}{\alpha^2} \bigg( e^{\alpha y} - e^{\alpha x} \bigg) +  e^{\alpha x} \bigg( x^2 - y^2 \bigg) > 0 \; \;?$$

Here, $\alpha > 0, y < x$.

**Additional information : both $x$ and $y$ are strictly greater than 0 !**

Comment: Is this related to probability or statistics?

Comment: Related to a problem of statistics.

Comment: This question if off-topic on CV since it does not relate anyhow to statistics, it fits rather http://math.stackexchange.com so I'm voting to migrate it there.

Comment: Which problem of statistics.is it related to, and in what manner?

Answer (score 2):

This is false.

Take $x = 0$ and $y = -\frac{1}{\alpha}$.  Then

$$\frac{2}{\alpha^2} \left( e^{\alpha y} - e^{\alpha x} \right) +  e^{\alpha x} \left( x^2 - y^2 \right) =  \frac{2}{\alpha^2} \left( e^{-1} - 1\right) + 1 \left(0 - \frac{1}{\alpha^2}\right)$$

Which simplifies to

$$ \frac{1}{\alpha^2} \left( 2 e^{-1} - 3 \right) $$

Which is negative

```
>>> 2 * exp(-1) - 3
-2.2642411176571153
```

Perhaps you are missing another constraint?

Comment: Sir, I have added the additional information. Can you now provide me with the solution ?

Answer (score 0):

It can be rewritten as:

[image]

Of which - under the constraints you specify - the leftmost two terms together are always < 0, and the rightmost two terms together are always > 0.

Which means that as long as the two rightmost terms together are larger than the two leftmost terms, you're fine.

Despite the fact that specific cases can be found for which this condition isn't met (as answered before, and proving the inequality as it is is false) there clearly are cases for which this constraint is met. For example $a = \sqrt2, x = 2, y = 1$. This will get you closer to finding that missing constraint which @Matthew Drury mentioned.

Comment: Well yes, proving that something is not always false (i.e. is at least sometimes true) is often easier than proving that it is always true.

Comment: That is of course true: nevertheless the inequality is true with an extra constraint, as was pointed out. I'm just helping identify the specific constraint. I've added a sentence to further clarify that intention.

Comment: Sirs, I have added the additional constraint that was required. Can this problem be now solved ?